# Is there an in-universe reason why the Hardy Boys don't always have access to Tom Swift-level technology?

Tags: tom-swift, hardy-boys

The Hardy Boys and Tom Swift have many crossover adventures. This clearly implies they're in the same universe.

[image]

Obviously, the Hardy Boys have full access to Tom Swift-level technology in the crossover adventures. And obviously, in the non-crossover adventures, they do not; Tom Swift being a sci-fi series with sci-fi level tech, while the Hardy Boys being a plain mystery series.

But being that they're set in the same universe, is there an in-universe explanation why the Hardy Boys don't have access to the Tom Swift tech in non-crossover books? Keep in mind that especially in the *Casefiles*, the Hardy Boys have access to government-level technology, so being a government secret cannot be the explanation.

Comment: It has been years since I have even thought about this series, so take this with a grain, but if they only have the tech when Tom swings by would that not mean that Tom is bringing it with him each time? Perhaps the Hardy Boys can't afford their own gear or they commonly operate in places that "shun" those types of advancements?...

Comment: Perhaps when sales of the Hardy Boys series was nosediving, they tried to do something to rescue it.  I wonder if even bringing in Tom Swift from another universe helped much.

Comment: I'd consider the crossovers to be separate canon.

Comment: @GEdgar  Given the timing, I would think the reverse.  The [Hardy Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hardy_Boys_books) have new books produced pretty continually (the last year without a new Hardy Boys was 1986).  It's the Tom Swift books that were nosediving in 1992 and 1993 (the years the two crossovers were produced).  There were no [Tom Swift books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tom_Swift_books) from 1994 through 2005.  It seems more likely they were trying to prop up Tom Swift than the Hardy Boys.  Of course, that's not an *in-universe* reason.